# Resharper data annotation on single line

Tags: c#, resharper

Im kind of new to resharper; but old on c#
I have a problem with the resharper config and on my team no ones knows how to solve it.

I have this:

```
 [Required]
 public ushort SemanticId { get; set; }
```

and every time that we make any modifications the Data Annotation and the prop goes into the same line; like this.

```
 [Required] public ushort SemanticId { get; set; }
```

Im using VS2022 and resharper 2023.2.2.

Best regards.

I have been searching on internet and cannot find a "solution" on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this setting via *ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Place property/indexer/event attribute on the same line*:
[image]